# Does Dameng have an equivalent to Oracle's DBMS_ASSERT.QUALIFIED_SQL_NAME() for SQL name validation?

Tags: sql, sql-injection

In Oracle, the function DBMS_ASSERT.QUALIFIED_SQL_NAME() is used to verify whether the input string is a legal SQL name, which helps prevent SQL injection. Is there a similar function in Dameng(A Chinese database)?

Find a function in Dameng similar to the DBMS_ASSERT.QUALIFIED_SQL_NAME() function in Oracle.